# intent in alart dialog

Tags: java, android, android-intent

intent in alart dialog  how pass in next intent

```
alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
                                  String  r=android.get(i).getPassword();

                                    if(title.equals(r)){

                                        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(activity,DetailView.class));
                                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext()," user name   " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                    else {
                                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext()," user name not valid  " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }



                                   // sendMessage(user.getId(), title, message);
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and post only relevant part of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use activity or context, for example, please refer below code

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, DetailView.class));
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

you can get activity or context from the contractor.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of the code:

```
view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(activity,DetailView.class));
```

To this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,Screen2Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Full code:

```
 alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
                                      String  r=android.get(i).getPassword();

                                        if(title.equals(r)){

                                           Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivityName.this,Screen2ActivityName.class);

        startActivity(intent);  
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext()," user name   " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                        else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext()," user name not valid  " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }



                                       // sendMessage(user.getId(), title, message);
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: startActivity() can you directly call? according to your answer, i thing is it not possible

Comment: bro it is working on my application

Comment: i thing i use this type of alertdialog in 15 to 17 application

Comment: I think you use alert dialog within an activity, but if you want to use out side of the activity so need to pass context.

Comment: yes bro.and according to this question not specify alert dialog within activity or fragment

Comment: so finally the question is wrong but the answer is true.

Comment: Yeh .mistake in question because new user post this question.